# Multiple Websites Access Right

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I have multiple websites on Odoo. How can I assign authorizations to different users or groups for each website?

Best regards.

Comment: This is a very broad question. There could be different complex approach and ideas to solve that. Most of them aren't built yet or need to be adapted to your situation. You could reach me in order to discuss more details if you really need this solved